# grep date from string

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to print any date value from a string. For example:

```
echo "08/08/2018 text here" | grep '/(0\d{1}|1[0-2])\/([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])\/(19|20)\d{2}/'
```

This returns no result. I want to print out only the date value, excluding the text here.

Comment: `echo "08/08/2018 text here" | cut -d " " -f 1`?

Comment: @Cyrus He says he wants to print *any* date value, not just the first field.

Comment: Grep doesn't use `/` delimiters around the regexp and you don't need to escape slash inside the regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` doesn't use `/` delimiters around the regexp, and doesn't need you to escape embedded `/`.

You need to use the `-P` option to use a PCRE regexp with GNU `grep`, so it will recognize `\d` for digits.

You should put `\b` around the regexp, to match word boundaries. Otherwise, if the input contains `108/08/2018` it will match the date that starts after `1`.

You need the `-o` option to print only the part of the line that matches, rather than the whole matching line.

```
echo "08/08/2018 text here" | grep -Po '\b(0\d{1}|1[0-2])/([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])\/(19|20)\d{2}\b'
```

Comment: How will fetch "08/08/18 text here"  this one

Comment: @SherinGreen My answer only works for 4-digit years from 1900 to 2099. it should be simple for you to modify it to allow 2-digit years.

Comment: OK Thanks, will try